# Получение ID в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

Здравствуйте, влзникла проблема необходимо из таблице выбрать все ID у которых поле в полу check стоит отметка(checkbox)

```js
$("#d1").click(function() {
  $('[cellspacing = 5]');
  var filterN = $('.form-control').is(':checked');


  $("#dynamic tr").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).find('#naim').text();
    if (n.search(new RegExp(filterN)) < 0) {
      console.log('не могу понять как выбрать если check true');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
TABLE {
  width: 300px;
  /* Ширина таблицы */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
}

TD,
TH {
  padding: 3px;
  /* Поля вокруг содержимого таблицы */
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Параметры рамки */
}

TH {
  background: #b0e0e6;
  /* Цвет фона */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamic" class="table table-striped table-dark">
  <thead>
    <td id="naim">ID</td>
    <td id="naim">comment</td>
    <td id="naim">Chek</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <td> 210</td>
    <td> Ю́рий Алексе́евич Гага́рин — лётчик-космонавт СССР № 1, Герой Советского Союза, кавалер высших знако</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <td> 211</td>
    <td> Альбе́рт Эйнште́йн — физик-теоретик, один из основателей современной теоретической физики, лауреат Н</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <td> 212</td>
    <td> Фили́пп Бедро́сович Кирко́ров — советский и российский эстрадный певец, актёр, композитор и продюсер</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <td> 214</td>
    <td> Марк Э́ллиот Цу́керберг — американский программист и предприниматель в области интернет-технологий, </td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <td> 215</td>
    <td> Илон Рив Маск — канадско-американский инженер, предприниматель, изобретатель и инвестор; долларовый </td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
    <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
    <td> 216</td>
    <td> NoName</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="sdfsdfsdfsfsf" id="d1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, но думаю есть более лаконичный вариант

**html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
          width: 300px;
          /* Ширина таблицы */
          border-collapse: collapse;
          /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
        }

        td,
        th {
          padding: 3px;
          /* Поля вокруг содержимого таблицы */
          border: 1px solid black;
          /* Параметры рамки */
        }

        th {
          background: #b0e0e6;
          /* Цвет фона */
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="dynamic" class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>
            <td id="id">ID</td>
            <td id="comment">comment</td>
            <td id="check">Chek</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> 210</td>
                <td> Ю́рий Алексе́евич Гага́рин — лётчик-космонавт СССР № 1, Герой Советского Союза, кавалер высших знако</td>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 211</td>
                <td> Альбе́рт Эйнште́йн — физик-теоретик, один из основателей современной теоретической физики, лауреат Н</td>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 212</td>
                <td> Фили́пп Бедро́сович Кирко́ров — советский и российский эстрадный певец, актёр, композитор и продюсер</td>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 214</td>
                <td> Марк Э́ллиот Цу́керберг — американский программист и предприниматель в области интернет-технологий, </td>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> 215</td>
                <td> Илон Рив Маск — канадско-американский инженер, предприниматель, изобретатель и инвестор; долларовый </td>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" value="0" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="get" id="d1" />
</body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
$("#d1").click(function() {
    var index = $('table thead td').index($('#id')); //находим индекс элемента с id = id

    $('.form-control').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //если нажат чекбокс то продолжаем
            var td_id = $(this).parents('tr').children().eq(index).html(); //находим tr в котором лежит чекбокс и из его детей берем index'овый элемент по счету т.е. наш id
            console.log(td_id);
        }
    });
});
```